# Passing JSON when invoking function using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am running a lambda function written in Go using Serverless and I want to pass a couple of parameters to it when it's invoked.

Here's the struct I created to receive the request:

```
type RequestStruct struct {
    StartAt int `json:"startAt"`
    EndAt   int `json:"endAt"`
}
```

And in the handler I'm trying to print out the values:

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context,request RequestStruct) (Response, error) {
    fmt.Printf("Request: %v",request)
```

I tried invoking it using the `--raw` option, so I tried doing this

`serverless invoke -f orders --raw -d '{"startAt":1533513600,"endAt":1534118399}'`

and I tried wrapping it in double quotes instead

`serverless invoke -f orders --raw -d "{startAt:1533513600,endAt:1534118399}"`

`serverless invoke -f orders --raw -d "{\"startAt\":1533513600,\"endAt\":1534118399}"`

I received a marshal error with all three:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.RequestStruct",
    "errorType": "UnmarshalTypeError"
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and I can find any examples for that online, there's only this [serverless doc about how to do the invoke](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke/) and this [aws doc about how to handle the event in Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-handler-types.html)

**Update**
I tried invoking the event from the AWS Console and it worked, so odds are the issue is in the serverless invoke command.

Comment: So did you used  `aws lambda invoke --function-name` CLI instead of serverless?

Comment: @DeepakSingh no, just through the console's UI I went to the lambda function and ran a test with the same json values

Comment: Okay, Did you tried `aws lambda invoke`? Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-userapp-walkthrough-custom-events-invoke.html.

Comment: I'd rather stick to the serverless framework because it'll require less maintenance as it'll pull the data from the same yml file that's being used to deploy the function

Comment: Seems like a bug with serverless invoke command , similar to reported issue   [link](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2685)

Comment: Oh, thanks for sharing that @ganapathydselva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around this by having my JSON in a file rather than in the command itself, this doesn't solve the issue I'm experiencing in the question but it's a way to invoke the function with Json

I added a `events/startAndEnd.json` file that contains my json data:

```
{
    "startAt":1533513600,
    "endAt":1534118399
}
```

And referenced that file in the invoke command: `serverless invoke -f orders --path events/startAndEnd.json`

Answer (score 0):

Incase you hit this issue when running the command via `npm`. I also had a similar error when invoking it with:

```
    "invoke": "serverless invoke --function myfunction --data \"{ \"Records\": []}\"",
```

By changing the double quotes to single quotes on the `data` it then suddenly started working:

```
    "invoke": "serverless invoke --function myfunction --data '{ \"Records\": []}'",
```